# Why do we say that a one-parameter subgroup "is" a homomorphism?

Tags: terminology, lie-groups

The definition of a one-parameter subgroup of a topological group $G$ is given as a particular group homomorphism $\phi: \Bbb{R} \rightarrow G$. I'm not sure I understand the terminology. Why do we say that the *homomorphism* is the subgroup rather than the *image* being the subgroup?

If I understand correctly, it has something to do with the parameterization being extra information attached to the group. For example, $t \mapsto e^{it}$ and $t \mapsto e^{i\omega t}$ (for $\omega \in \Bbb{R}_{\ne 0}$) have the same image, but if we imagine that the elements of $\Bbb{C}^\times$ "remember where they came from," then we can distinguish the resulting groups. Presumably this has some use that I will learn soon.

I don't think I've come across this kind of pattern before, where we can attach additional information to an algebraic structure without thinking of it as a new kind of structure. Is this common?

Comment: I think you're just noticing that the terminology is misleading. A "one-parameter subgroup" sounds like it should be a subgroup with a particular property (of being "one-parameter"), but it's actually defined as this homomorphism which (as you point out) carries more information than just its image. Another example of "<adjective> <noun>" being defined as something that's not technically a <noun> is "partial function".

Comment: Oh, I see. Yeah that would be a simple explanation, huh? Thanks!

Comment: @Karl May I suggest that you write that comment as an answer? (With, perhaps, an added citation of some kind---I am unfamiliar with this use of terminology and am curious to see it in context.)

Comment: My comment is the "safe" way of looking at it, but there's probably some motivation for conflating the homomorphism with its image. For example, $t\mapsto \omega t$ is an isomorphism of $(\Bbb{R},+)$, so the different homomorphisms OP describes are in a sense equivalent. Maybe there's a more general version of this observation.

Comment: Putting Karl's comment another way, the question isn't so much "Why do we say that a one-parameter subgroup is a homomorphism?" but "Why do we use the word "subgroup" to describe a homomorphism?"

Comment: This is anyway one of the worse examples of the mathematical terminology antipattern of "[adjective] [noun]" not being a "[noun]". At least "skew field" is still a type of ring.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively you can think of the parameter $t$ as a time parameter. That means the homomorphism tells you how "fast" the one-parameter subgroup is going, and its image doesn't. I like to think specifically about one-parameter subgroups of $SO(3)$, which correspond to "motions" of the form "rotate in this direction this quickly."

Remembering the homomorphism also lets you differentiate it to get an element of the Lie algebra. It just turns out to be a really good idea. The image is not quite enough information.

Comment: Thanks! In retrospect, there are two questions that I didn't separate clearly. One is what you've answered: why bother remembering the parameterization? I'm not sure I've come across an example where the speed matters, but perhaps I will. And thanks for pointing out that *parameterization* matters for recovering the Lie algebra, even if speed does not. The second question is the one I really meant to ask here: why use the word "subgroup" to name a homomorphism? I wasn't sure if this was indicative of a broader pattern in math that I've missed.

Comment: Probably just historical inertia, if I had to guess. Although as Karl says, it is actually reasonably common in mathematics for "[adjective] [noun]" to refer to something that isn't a [noun], but is a generalization of a [noun].